# Android: click doesn't work on Recycler Item after swiping

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, swipe-gesture, android-nestedscrollview

I implemented `Recycler` swipe effect by `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` and put some buttons on the back view which shows after swiping. the funny problem is that when I clicked button the don't work. I should press them twice and in the third try they work!!! this is a gif:
[image: third try]

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT ) {

            @Override
            public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                int dragFlags = 0;
                int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
                return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
  ((InvoiceItemListAdapter.ViewHolder)viewHolder).lunchSwipeLeftEffect(dX);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {

            }
        };

        recentInvoicesItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        recentInvoicesItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recentInvoiceRecyclerView);
```

and this is my `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`:

```
private class RecentInvoiceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView price;
    private TextView hours;
    private TextView minutes;
    private TextView desc;
    private View color;
    private View sent;
    private View swipeActionsView;
    private View frontView;
    private Button print;
    private Button cancelSwipe;

    boolean swiped = false;

    public RecentInvoiceViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        price    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invoice_review_in_day_price);
        hours    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invoice_review_in_day_hours);
        minutes  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invoice_review_in_day_minutes);
        desc     = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invoice_review_in_day_decs);
        color    =  view.findViewById(R.id.invoice_review_in_day_color);
        sent     =  view.findViewById(R.id.invoice_review_in_day_sent_check);
        swipeActionsView     =  view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_actions);
        frontView     =  view.findViewById(R.id.front_view);
        print     = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.print_recent_invoice);
        cancelSwipe     = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_swipe);

        cancelSwipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                frontView.setTranslationX(0);
                frontView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                swiped = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void lunchSwipeEffect(float dx){
        if(!swiped)
            frontView.setTranslationX(dx);//TranslationX(dx);
        if(Math.abs(dx)> frontView.getMeasuredWidth()) {
            swiped = true;
            frontView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

and finally this is my `ViewHolder` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_invoice_item_height"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_margin"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_actions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        android:clickable="false">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontButton
                android:id="@+id/print_recent_invoice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_font"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="print"
                style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"
                android:layout_column="0"/>
            <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_font"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="print"
                style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
            <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_font"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="print"
                style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"
                android:layout_column="2"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontButton
                android:id="@+id/cancel_swipe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_font"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="cancel"
                style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"
                android:layout_column="0"/>
            <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_font"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="print"
                style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
            <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_font"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="print"
                style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"
                android:layout_column="2"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/front_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:clickable="true"
        >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/invoice_review_in_day_color"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_colored_view_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/invoice_review_box_radius_right_shape"/>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/invoice_review_in_day_color"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/invoice_review_main_box_radius_shape"
            android:padding="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_border">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="@integer/archived_right_one_day_item_top_invoice_section_weight"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/invoice_review_box_radius_top_left_shape"
                android:padding="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_top_section_padding">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontTextView
                        android:id="@+id/invoice_review_in_day_hours"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_margin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_font"
                        android:textColor="@color/archived_right_one_day_item_time_text_color"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/clock_background"
                        style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"/>
                    <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_separator_font"
                        android:textColor="@color/archived_right_one_day_item_time_text_color"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_separator_margin_top"/>
                    <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontTextView
                        android:id="@+id/invoice_review_in_day_minutes"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_margin"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_time_font"
                        android:textColor="@color/archived_right_one_day_item_time_text_color"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/clock_background"
                        style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/archived_right_one_day_item_total_title"
                        android:textColor="#6d6d6d"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_price_title_font"
                        android:gravity="bottom|right"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"/>

                    <ir.masna.hetab.views.AutoResize.AutoResizeTextView
                        android:id="@+id/invoice_review_in_day_price"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_price_font"
                        android:gravity="top|right"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="@integer/archived_right_one_day_item_bottom_invoice_section_weight"
                android:background="@drawable/invoice_review_box_radius_bottom_left_shape">

                <ir.masna.hetab.views.IranFontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/invoice_review_in_day_decs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:textColor="@color/archived_right_one_day_item_time_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_desc_font"
                    android:padding="@dimen/archived_right_one_day_item_desc_padding"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/invoice_review_in_day_sent_check"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    style="@style/CustomFontStyleYekan" />
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/invoice_review_in_day_sent_check"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/tick"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

and the recyclerView is in a `NestedScrollView` with collapsing toolbar effect.
Which Views consumes two first click?!

Comment: By any chance, did you find any luck on this ? I got stuck in same situation..

Comment: Did anyone find a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemTouchHelper` is gripping the touch from the `RecyclerView`

Comment: Please elaborate on this cause and provide a solution. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How I solved:

1.) Create two layouts in xml file (one for swipeable layout, one for the background layout with buttons)
Set swipeableLayout to VISIBLE and backgroundLayout to GONE

2.) Create a variable in the row data to keep track of whether that row has been swiped by the user. (Example: email.**isBackgroundMenuBehindSwipeOverlayVisible** = false

When user swipes to remove a row (triggers ItemTouchHelper.onSwiped()), set the row's isBackgroundMenuBehindSwipeOverlayVisible = true. This persists a field we can use when refreshing the adapter.

3.) (This part is cringe, but it's the ONLY solution so far on this issue)
Replace the **entire** adapter with a brand new one:
Ex.)

email?.isBackgroundMenuBehindenterSwipeOverlayVisible = true // Persist user swipe to show menu on this row when the adapter is refreshed.

val savedLinearLayoutManagerState = linearLayoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState() // To persist users scroll position before scrapping adapter

inboxAdapter = inboxAdapter(requireContext(), recentThreads)

linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

binding.inboxRecyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

binding.inboxRecyclerView.adapter = inboxAdapter

linearLayoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(savedLinearLayoutManagerState)
// Return the user to the position they were when they swiped.